# error in POST request with cURL on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, post, curl

I am trying to send a POST request to my localhost using cURL on my Windows 10. I am using Ruby on Rails and my database is PostgresQL. I tried all the solutions posted on everywhere but none of them is working.

This is what a type into cURL:

`curl -v -g -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: NVNNymcrAExBdDsaje9z" -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/reservations -d '{"reservation": {"venue":"new Venue", "venue_id":"1", "reservation_date":"2016/04/26", "num_people":"3", "num_bottles":"1"}}'`

This is the error I am getting:

```
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: {venue:new Venue,/
* Could not resolve host: {venue
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: {venue
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: venue_id:1,/
* Could not resolve host: venue_id
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: venue_id
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: reservation_date
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: reservation_date
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: num_people:3,/
* Could not resolve host: num_people
* Closing connection 4
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: num_people
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: num_bottles:1}}'/
* Could not resolve host: num_bottles
* Closing connection 5
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: num_bottles
```

I tried using escape quotes like this:

```
curl -v -g -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: NVNNymcrAExBdDsaje9z" -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/reservations/ -d {\"reservation\": {\"venue\":\"new Venue\", \"venue_id\":\"1\", \"reservation_date\":\"2016/04/26\", \"num_people\":\"3\", \"num_bottles\":\"1\"}}
```

This is the error I get with the escape quotes:

```
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: {"venue":"new/
* Could not resolve host: {"venue"
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: {"venue"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: Venue",/
* Could not resolve host: Venue",
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Venue",
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: "venue_id":"1",/
* Could not resolve host: "venue_id"
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "venue_id"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: "reservation_date"
* Closing connection 4
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "reservation_date"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: "num_people":"3",/
* Could not resolve host: "num_people"
* Closing connection 5
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "num_people"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Rebuilt URL to: "num_bottles":"1"}}/
* Could not resolve host: "num_bottles"
* Closing connection 6
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "num_bottles"
```

I also tried moving my data files inside the curl/bin and use -d @text.txt like this:

```
curl -v -g -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: NVNNymcrAExBdDsaje9z" -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/reservations -d @text.txt
```

This is the error:

```
    Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

I am open to any suggestions? What do you think my problem is? How do I fix this and make a proper POST request?

Comment: connecting to port 3000 failed - you don't have a HTTP server listening to it

Comment: @DanielStenberg Hey, thanks for your reply. I don't think that is the problem because everything seems to be fine when I ping it

Comment: ping and connecting to its TCP port 3000 are two very different things...

Comment: @DanielStenberg Sorry I wasn't being clear enough. I also have a localhost:3000/ping route

Comment: what does that even mean? "Connection refused" means that curl couldn't connect to the TCP port 3000 of your machine, it's as simple as that.